# Getting NULL when calling kafkatemplate.send() instead of ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>>

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I am sending message to kafka using below code.

ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future =
kafkaTemplate.send("topic", 1L);

While writing JUnit test case, I am getting null pointer ex. send method is returning null instead of ListenableFuture.

I have written below code. Please help.

```
@Test
public void publishDataToKafka() {
    String key = "topic1";
    String topic = "topicuser1";
    long offset = 1L;
    int partition = 1;

    SendResult<String, String> sendResult = mock(SendResult.class);
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> responseFuture = mock(ListenableFuture.class);
    RecordMetadata recordMetadata = new RecordMetadata(new TopicPartition(topic, partition), offset, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0, 0);
    given(sendResult.getRecordMetadata()).willReturn(recordMetadata);
    when(kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message)).thenReturn(responseFuture);

    producer.produce(data);
}
```

Comment: can you share junit code here?

Comment: Added junit code.